# Access wrist position in Kinect using C#

Tags: kinect

Sorry if this is rather obvious, but how would I be able to access the position of the wrist joint for the Kinect in C#? Would it really be as simple as:

```
 SkeletonPoint leftWrist = skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position;
 SkeletonPoint rightWrist = skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position;
```

And I would call

```
leftWrist.X.toString
```

To check the value, right?

But what would the for loop look like to continue tracking the joints in every frame? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can track that wrist position of the active players.  All the joints that are available for tracking exist within the [Skeleton.Joints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.skeleton.joints.aspx) property (itself a 'JointCollection').

[image]

Microsoft provides a tutorial for tracking the skeleton here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx

The values returned are of type [Joint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.joint.aspx).